# Rotate object around the world axis

Tags: javascript, rotation, three.js

I found several different supposedly working ways to rotate an object around the world axis but all of them kept rotating the object around it's own axis instead of rotating it around the world's. So, what's the proper way to rotate an object around the world's axis?

If I wasn't clear about the problem here's a drawing that represents my problem

[image]

Edit: Sorry I should have specificated in the question as well that I'm using Three.js

Edit2:

```
//camera is the object I want to rotate 
//I also found a method that uses Euler but the result was far from the expected

/**Method 1**/

//Found this somewhere here in so
var rotateAroundWorldAxis = function(object, axis, radians) {
  var rotWorldMatrix;
  rotWorldMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
  rotWorldMatrix.makeRotationAxis(axis.normalize(), radians);
  rotWorldMatrix.multiply(object.matrix);
  object.matrix = rotWorldMatrix;
  object.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(object.matrix);
}

//this is how I call the method
rotateAroundWorldAxis(camera, new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), movementX*-0.001);
rotateAroundWorldAxis(camera, new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), movementY*-0.001);
/**Method 1**/


/**Method 2**/
//I've also tried this method
var q = new THREE.Quaternion();

q.setFromAxisAngle( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), movementX*-0.001 ); // axis must be normalized, angle in radians
camera.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions( q, camera.quaternion );
/**Method 2**/


//movementX and movementY are values provided by the mouse movement using the pointerlock. 
//These values works as I've tried them using rotateOnAxis
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Had a look on CSS rotate transforms and transform-origin properties?

Comment: Forgot to mention in the question I'm using Three.js

Comment: javascript does not matter.. i'd suggest try using transform-origin property from css

Comment: Well I'm not familiar with this property. I'll read more about it and try.

Comment: I don't see how this property would help as I don't understand how this could be used in a 3D world. Could you please shed me some light?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal this is not at all related to CSS ...

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal mixing css transforms and threejs is for special case only. Rotations and kinematics are provided in threejs as quaternions http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion You'll need to post some code to start with as it may have been a simple error in your attempt.

Comment: I've edited the post with some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the FirstPersonControls class. I had to make a few changes to the class though

Answer (score 0):

Use quaternions.

```
var rotateAroundWorldAxis = function(object, axis, radians) {
  var rotation = new THREE.Quaternion();
  rotation.setFromAxisAngle ( axis, radians );
  object.quaternion.multiply(rotation);
}

rotateAroundWorldAxis(myObject, THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), movementX*-0.001);
```

I believe your problem before with the quaternion method is multiplying the quaternions **in the wrong order** so you rotate around global the Y axis, then perform the local rotation, which ultimately rotates in the local Y axis.

Comment: In the quaternion method I just did 2 rotations (axis X and Y). I'm going to try to mess with jsfiddle and see if I can reproduce my problem. Btw I've tried your code but the result is the same

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem in jsfiddle because for some reason the canvas wasn't updating no matter the changes I made, so I made a vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MTfBoR3LfqY&feature=youtu.be. In this vídeo I'm rotating the cube down and then left. Sorry about the bad quality